Civi with custom theme broke permalinks
I have a problem with Civi + my custom theme, and I can't figure out why this is happening and how to fix it.
So, this is my site: https://civicrm.ams-net.org/
Without civi everything is working fine, but with it almost every page give 404 error.
And for some reason, only archive pages like this works https://civicrm.ams-net.org/funding/. Also, search is working too.
How can I figure our what in my theme can cause conflicts with civi?

Welcome to SE!   If you switch to a core theme with Civi, does it work?
